# socket.io client making 2 connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I've tried using the [options](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/) mentioned on socketio's website to increase the time before reconnection, disabling connection upgrade from http to websocket, enabling the forceNew option. But there's always 2 connections whenever the client page loads.
Anyone has any idea on what is going on. I'm eager to give more information if required. Thank you for reading this.

**Client Code( React.js + TailwindCSS )**

```js
import "./App.css";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import Home from "./pages/Home/Home";

function App() {
  const socket = io("http://localhost:3000/");
  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log(socket.id);
    console.log(socket.connected);
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Server Code (Node.js)**

```js
import http from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3001",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (client) => {
  console.log("client connected", client.id);
  client.on("event", (data) => {});
  client.on("disconnect", () => {});
});

server.listen(3000);
server.on("listening", () => console.log("listening"));
```

**Client Console**

```
2zcCMTkpbDtW-R5jAAA-
true
KdzGTWRxUIhlk0bKAAA_
true
```

**Server Console**

```
listening
client connected zh1zj5dnUb55zUdrAAAB
client connected rQexCoY7B6Es_r_RAAAD
```

[image: Chrome console output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initiate the socket inside a `useEffect` hook, otherwise, it will run each time your component rerenders.

In this case, `io` function will trigger only once, since the `useEffect` has no dependencies, it will run one time only. Also, make sure to close the connection once your App is unmounted

```
function App() {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const s = io("http://localhost:3000/");
    setSocket(s);

    return () => s.disconnect();
  }, [setSocket]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}
```